# Mysql - set value from regex on column

Tags: mysql, regex

I've got 2 VARCHAR Column :

```
Score  | S |
-------+---+
0 / 64 |   |
10/64  |   |
NF     |   |
-------+---+
```

Is it possible to create a stocked procedure who take the value of the column Score and set the value of the column S with the match of a regex expression on the Score value ?

**Example**

```
0 / 64 -> 0
10 / 64 -> 10
NF -> NULL
```

```
Regex /\s*([0-9]*)\s*\/
```

**Expected result**

```
Score  | S   |
-------+-----+
0 / 64 | 0   |
10/64  | 10  |
NF     | NULL|
-------+-----+
```

Thanks

Comment: Is NF specific to NULL or anything that isn't in the `# /#` format should be NULL?

Comment: Perhaps non-regex solution works? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bTv1tqxmdAYjAcT2WZqKZi/0

Comment: `SELECT 0 + SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '/', 1) ..`

Answer (score 0):

Good day. Here is the code. You can try on website [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be80404291c675bc84fed98b705433d1).
First of all, I tried to write the code "Nested Regexp_Replace". Second you can assign "NULL" value by using "CASE WHEN" clause instead of "NF" values then you can implement one single "Regexp_Replace" function to solve this.

```
SQL>
SELECT COL,REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'([0-9]+)(\/)([0- 
9]+)','$1'),'NF','NULL') AS RESULT
FROM 
(
SELECT '0/64' AS COL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10/64' AS COL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'NF' AS COL FROM DUAL 
) A

RESULT
--------------
COL     RESULT
0/64      0
10/64    10
NF      NULL
SQL>
```